# Patch link turning into get when opened in new tab?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, http-verbs

I have a PATCH link that works normally when people click on it... but for some reason, when a user clicks on the link to open in a new tab, I get a routing error saying this path does not exist for GET.

```
<%= link_to "Create Note", member_create_tnote_path, method: :patch, class: 'btn btn-default' %>
```

I've confirmed its happening on more than one machine... I'm baffled...

Comment: Yes, that is how it works. Because `patch` only works with JavaScript, without Javascript it is a simple `get`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the answer.

The problem is that link_to is intended for get... button_to is intended for patch.

Updated links to button_to... and everything is working properly.

Comment: You should accept your own answer, so others will know it was successful, maybe it will help out the next person :)